# How to get redirected to a specific page after scanning QR-code

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, qr-code

I've searched google but didn't find anything about my issue. I want to link QR-codes to a specific company in the app. I saw that you can generate QR-codes and then add a URL to them. However, I do see how I would go about to add my preferred behaviour in the app.

After scanning the QR-code I want to be redirected to that company's specific page. Do I have to set up an ID in the database or something similar?

Appreciate the help!! :)

UPDATE:

This is the code I used. I just downloaded the sample project to see if I could figure it out.

https://blog.verslu.is/xamarin/xamarin-forms-xamarin/scanning-generating-barcodes-zxing/

Comment: What are you using to scan the code? Where is the code that executes the scan?

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve]

Comment: @Steve Updated the question. As of right now im only showing a displayalert of the url in the qr-code.

Comment: @JohnB Updated question. As of right now im only showing a displayalert of the url in the qr-code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It totally depends on what value you put in the QR code. If you have some kind of company ID, then yes, you would have to go through the database (or wherever you saved the details of the company corresponding to that ID), get the URL and then simply do a `Device.OpenUri()` call to that URL.

You can also encode the actual URL in the QR code. Then you can simply retrieve the value from that and navigate directly to it from that same `Device.OpenUri()` call.

In code, you will just hook into the method that handles the scanned result, like this:

```
public void Handle_OnScanResult(Result result)
{
  Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
  {
    await DisplayAlert("Scanned result", result.Text, "OK");
  });
}
```

The `result.Text` will be the contents of your QR code. This can be whatever you want. An ID, a URL, etc. so depending on what it in there, you can show it in a dialog as I did, or navigate to a URL.

Does this answer your question? Btw, thanks for reading my blog! :)